# When implementing a WizardExportResourcesPage, how can I modify the selected resources?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, export, selection, wizard

My custom Export Wizard implements a WizardExportResourcesPage. The initially selected resources are whichever workspace resources were selected when the user clicked Export.

However the eclipse project contains a .settings folder, as well as a .project file. I want these files to be unselected by default, and/or maybe even hidden in the resources list.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Override the method `hasExportableExtension` and here check if the resource matches settings/project and return false for files you dont want to export.